# code not work on for HtmlunitDriver whereas same code work well for FirefoxDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

When  tried to execute the below code on FirefoxDriver(), code is executed very well.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

But When tried to execute the same code with HtmlUnitDriver()

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

It throws an error

```
public void controller (String col1) throws Throwable{

        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        driver.get("http://sitename.com/signup");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='FN']")).sendKeys("test");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LN']")).sendKeys("test");
```

Getting below error

```
htmlTextInput[<input class="span10" type="text" name="FN" value="" id="FN" autocomplete="off">] -> HtmlHtml[<html>]
HtmlTextInput[<input class="span10" type="text" name="FN" value="" id="FN" autocomplete="off">] -> HtmlHtml[<html>]
HtmlTextInput[<input class="span10" type="text" name="FN" value="" id="FN" autocomplete="off">] -> HtmlHtml[<html>]
HtmlBody[<body>] -> HtmlHtml[<html>]
```

Comment: Behavior of html unti driver is really unpredictable and besides, you can't actually see the things happening.It might be unable to load java scripts and other required things.You can give a try by enabling java script for Html unit driver. `driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: If a headless browser is your requirement, you might also try PhantomJS